# Query Remote mysql database from php and get result set

Tags: java, php, mysql, remote-access

I have my website(in php) running in **Yahoo small business** and Application(in java) in **Rackspace.com**.both server has got mysql database.

I want to query my application database(in rackspace) from my website(in Yahoo) and get the result set.

How to do it?
Please suggest me reference document to do it.

Is it a good idea to directly query a remote database ? means is there any performance issue will rise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a bad idea to remotely access data that do not "belong" to your app. In this case, the PHP app should access a set of functions that are exposed on the Java side. This is to make sure that when you upgrade the Java side, you may change the schema of the database without affecting anyone interacting with it.

I recommend you look into Web Services -- there are many methods (eg look for RPC, REST, SOAP), and some might be a better fit for your needs than others.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the database port, it should be easy but unsecure.
If you can access the database port in a secure manner (for example vpn tunnel), it would be easy and secure :)

My suggestion would be to implement the querys as SOAP Services in the Application and access them via PHP. Google should provide enough Results about SOAP in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK

if you would like to use the java function from php you should implement the web services in java in any of the web service types

You can access web services from php using the [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php) calls